# Python script does not restart properly with systemd

Tags: python, systemd

I am learning how to restart a Python script in case of error (following [this](https://youtu.be/TXSPPT6_qTY) tutorial, however with some small tweaks regarding filenames and alike). First things first, the needed files:

- `/home/myuser/Desktop/test/test.py`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

path = "/home/dec13666/Desktop/test/log.txt"

while True:
    with open(path, "a") as f:
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        f.write(now+"\n")
        f.close()
    sleep(1)
    raise Exception("Error Simulation!!!")
```

- `davidcustom.service`:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Python Script Made By Me
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
ExecStart=python3 /home/myuser/Desktop/test/test.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally, the commands run:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/davidcustom.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable davidcustom.service
sudo systemctl start davidcustom.service
sudo systemctl status davidcustom.service
```

The message I am getting:

```bash
● davidcustom.service - Python Script Made By Me
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/davidcustom.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-09-04 14:12:12 EDT; 8s ago
    Process: 3341 ExecStart=python3 /home/myuser/Desktop/test/test.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3341 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 100ms
```

Notes:

- When I run `test.py` manually, it works OK, but then that python script is run from a service (as seen here), it generates that error.
- I have tried to set `User=myusername` and `Type=simple`, in `davidcustom.service` (`[Service]`), with no difference in the results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the full path to the `python3` executable, it might not be in the default `PATH`

Comment: You might pipe stdout and stderr into a file so you can see the output.  You also might use a shebang line (`#! /usr/bin/env pythone`) and make the script executable, instead of invoking the interpreter separately.

Comment: Do you get any writes at all? You could wrap the whole script in a try/except and post any exception to the system logger.

Comment: You could add `user=youruser` and `group=yourgroup` to the `[system]` section.

Comment: Actually, just look at syslog. `f.write(now+"\n")` doesn't have the proper indentation.

Comment: Oops, meant "User" and "group" - then you are not running as root and file creation gets the right user/group ownership.

Comment: @Barmar, I have added a comment in your answer, it is not the root cause, issue remains.

Comment: Hello @tdelaney, Did not realize about the indentation, which was the root cause for my issue. Actually and for some reason, when using "Text Editor" the indentation was OK (which I inadvertently copied & pasted here), but then I realized about your comment. I corrected afterwards with nano, and it worked. I will keep the rest of your suggestions in mind, for future cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inadvertently added some wrong indentation in the original code (corrected by now in the original post). That solved my issue; when running `sudo systemctl status davidcustom.service`, now the service is `active`:

```bash
● davidcustom.service - Python Script Made By Dave
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/davidcustom.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-09-04 16:16:02 EDT; 23ms ago
   Main PID: 4287 (python3)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 14215)
     Memory: 3.0M
        CPU: 16ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/davidcustom.service
             └─4287 python3 /home/dec13666/Desktop/test/test.py
```

Other suggestions which would worth keeping in mind, but were NOT necessary for my case (thanks @Barmar & @tdelaney):

- Use an absolute path at `ExecStart` (easily obtainable by running `which python` command)
- If you only want to use your User and/or Group, then explicitely write those parameters.
- The 2 previous suggestions should be added in `[Service]`, in your service script:

```
[Service]
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/Desktop/test/test.py
User=youruser
Group=yourgroup
```

- Read the comments in the original post, for other options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ExecStart` requires an absolute path to the executable, it doesn't search `$PATH`. So use

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/Desktop/test/test.py
```

(assuming that's where `python3` is installed -- you can use `type python3` to get the actual location).

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python3`...

Comment: It works on my ubuntu without a full path.

Comment: `which python3` command returns `/usr/bin/python3`, which I have updated in my `ExecStart` parameter; not the root cause though, error remains. Plus, as mentioned by @tdelaney, in the videotutorial, it works without providing the full path.

Comment: @tdelaney indeed, the indentation was the root cause. I have added some more comments, as response to some of your own, in my original post. Thank you.